# Bootstrap 4 row & column stacking vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I feel like this should be easy, but I'm trying to get my .temp and .city divs to be side-by-side, but they're stacking vertically instead.

I've tried changing the size of the columns, but they always stack on top of each other. Any ideas?

```
          <div class="col-lg" id="col2">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg">
                <div class="wind"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg" id="col3">
                <div class="temp"></div>
                <div class="city"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit your code to this, making the second row have two columns.

```
<div class="col-lg" id="col2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg">
            <div class="wind"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col temp"></div>
            <div class="col city"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap `temp` div and `city` div into 2 different columns. Check this [Bootstrap4 Example](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#equal-width).

```css
.wind,
.temp,
.city {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="col-sm" id="col2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg">
      <div class="wind"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg" id="col3">
      <div class="temp"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg" id="col3">
      <div class="city"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I would like there to be two rows: The first row to have the .wind div, and the second row to have .temp & .city, side-by-side.  Does that makes sense?

Comment: oh I saw esther kay added an answer, yeah, same solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can rearrange your html code to this format.

```
        <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-lg" id="col2">
                <div class="col-lg">
                    <div class="wind"></div>
                </div>
            </div>            
            <div class="col-lg" id="col3">
                <div class="temp"></div>
                <div class="city"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```